# dynamicaly create "button" image with hover text

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I need to create a clickable image with dynamicaly getted text over it.
I already have the php that get the information needed for text but i'm having trouble creating the button(i'm really new to this kind of stuff).
This is an example of what I'd like to create:

[image]

The text "A020310" its a php answer and change all the time(saved in 'stringaPosizione', value of the button). A variable number of this image will be created and will be clicked to start some operation.

I have a javascript code that create button but they dont have image:

```
//Create an input type dynamically.
var element = document.createElement("input");

//Assign different attributes to the element.
element.setAttribute("type", "button");
element.setAttribute("class", "mybutt");
element.setAttribute("value", stringaPosizione);
element.setAttribute("name", idMappatura);
element.onclick = function() { runCommand(this) };
```

css:

```
.mybutt {
    background-image: url(/box.png);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px -1px 20px 1px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px -1px 20px 1px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px -1px 20px 1px #ffffff;
    background-color:transparent;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    border:5px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#777777;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:10px 40px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 3px 4px #ffffff;
}
.mybutt:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: to me, size is missing to make button fit image size in background.

Answer (score 2):

Do you are appending the `element` on any object ? If not, you're just creating an element on the browser memory but not appending it to the dom tree.

Furthermore, you have to set the dimensions of your button to show the entire image.

Look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NAeGK/) and tell me if something is missing.

Comment: yes i'm appending it:
    var foo = document.getElementById("fooBart");
    //Append the element in page (in span).
    foo.appendChild(element);

i will check the link, thx

Comment: may I suggest again you were missing size (heigh/width) :). You might even use line-height instead vertical padding to set text on bottom area, with a touch of text-shadow to make more readable.

Comment: @GCyrillus Agreed, but I think this details are up to him.